# Unable to pass parameter into evaluate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to pass background-color as a parameter to evaluate function like the way shown in the code below:

```
const loc = await page.waitForSelector("#Login");
const style = 'background-color';
const thecssStyle = await page.evaluate(el =>
  window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(style),loc
);
console.log("Print :"+thecssStyle);
```

This does not work and I get the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: style is not defined

But if I pass the background-color directly like shown below it works absolutely fine:

```
const loc = await page.waitForSelector("#Login");
const thecssStyle = await page.evaluate(el =>
  window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('background-color'),loc
);
console.log("Print :"+thecssStyle);
```

I want to pass background-color as parameter rather than passing it directly how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the `style` in the same way you pass the `loc`

```js
const loc = await page.waitForSelector("#Login");
const style = 'background-color';
const thecssStyle = await page.evaluate(
  (el, style) => window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(style),
  loc,
  style
);
console.log("Print :"+thecssStyle);
```